# Charging a Garmin Oregon GPS

Tags: gps, dynamo, garmin, battery, charging

Does anyone know if you can charge a Garmin Oregon GPS from a bicycle hub dynamo with the optional rechargeable batteries? Thanks Karl.

Comment: It's unlikely to work without some custom electronics, unless the manual say so.  Bike dynamos actually put out AC, and a charging input probably expects DC; the voltage will also vary.  If you're on the desktop version of the site, have a look at the "Related" sidebar

Comment: Something like http://www.peterwhitecycles.com/b&musbwerk.php may be an option

Comment: @Batman that could convince me to get a dynamo hub. Nice find

Comment: @ChrisH - there have been a few others , for a while. The only thing is that you have to charge before the ride -- the amount of power your dyno gives is not going to be enough to charge it up most likely, so it'll just act as a battery extender.

Comment: @Batman I'm familiar with B&M, giving me some confidence in them. Just not running down (e.g. my phone with a 0.5A source and the screen on) would be good.  It becomes a question of whether I want to learn to build wheels, and whether I want to spend the money (or even more money and have it built), as I haven't seen an off-the-shelf dynohub wheel I want.

Comment: @ChrisH - The other option is to carry a battery pack. I havent seen figures on how much longer a modern phone can be extended with one of these, versus just carrying a battery pack.

Comment: @Batman that's the plan for tomorrow's ride!  I was already thinking about dynamo lighting but the lack of versatility in the output (vs the investment) put me off.

Comment: I have an Oregon 650 and the Garmin branded rechargables are pretty bad.  I would suggest buying a pair of high quality NiMH AA's and taping a shim to them to activate the switch used to enable in-unit charging.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - I have done this using a [SP PD-8](http://www.sp-dynamo.com/8seriesdynamo%20hub.html) and a [Sinewave Reactor](http://www.sinewavecycles.com/collections/chargers/products/sinewave-cycles-reactor) .  However, it's easier if you use the Reactor to charge a cache battery, and then charge the Garmin from that.  This is because the Garmin will try to switch off whenever you stop if it's running directly off the USB out of the Reactor.